# Call Parameterized constructor from Array In java

Tags: java, arrays, class

I am having `Employee` class as

```
 public class Employee {
       Employee(String ,fName,String lName,String company,String dept){
           this.fName=fName;
           this.lName=lName;
           this.company=company;
           this.dept=dept;
       }
 }
```

In the `Service` Method i am using like

```
    Map employeDataMap = getEmpData(empId);
    final String FIELD_ARRAY["fName","lName","company","dept"]
    Employee e = new Employee (
        map.get(FIELD_ARRAY[0]).toString(),map.get(FIELD_ARRAY[1]).toString(),map.get(FIELD_ARRAY[2]).toString(),map.get(FIELD_ARRAY[3]).toString()
     )
```

Everything is working fine but i want to populate constructor dynamically rather than `0,1,2,4`

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: Create a constructor which accepts that `Map` and pulls any values that match your field names. But if you're just looking to do it _dynamically_, there's zero reason you can't use the first constructor. (I assumed this was some kind of deserialization)

Comment: @hev1 instead of `map.get(FIELD_ARRAY[0]).toString()` i want `forEach` on array in constructor